# Talk interactively in C with another C program on Linux not working

Tags: c, linux, pipe, exec, interactive

I am trying to talk interactively with a `C` executable on Linux (give input on stdin and read output from stdout).

I am using a `C` program `host.c` and talking to a compiled executable `target.c`.
However, the output is not as expected. Especially giving input to `target.c` does not work.

Here is my full code:

**host.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct PStd {
  FILE *p_stdin;
  FILE *p_stdout;
};


// Like popen(), but returns two FILE*: child's stdin and stdout, respectively.
struct PStd* popen2(const char *executableCommand)
{
    // pipes[0]: parent writes, child reads (child's stdin)
    // pipes[1]: child writes, parent reads (child's stdout)
    int pipes[2][2];

    pipe(pipes[0]);
    pipe(pipes[1]);

    if (fork() > 0)
    {
        // parent
        close(pipes[0][0]);
        close(pipes[1][1]);


        struct PStd *output = (struct PStd *) malloc(sizeof(struct PStd));
        output->p_stdin = fdopen(pipes[0][1], "w");
        output->p_stdout = fdopen(pipes[1][0], "r");
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        // child
        close(pipes[0][1]);
        close(pipes[1][0]);

        dup2(pipes[0][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipes[1][1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", executableCommand, NULL);
        // execl(executableCommand, executableCommand, NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    printf("HOST BEGIN\n");
    sleep(1);
    struct PStd *values = popen2("./target.out");

    if (values->p_stdin == NULL || values->p_stdout == NULL)
    {
        printf("popen2() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("popen2() success\n");

    setvbuf(values->p_stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(values->p_stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    
    
    // const char msg[] = "Hello there!\n";
    char buf[320];

    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
    printf("LOGS 0\n");
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), values->p_stdout)==NULL);
    printf("LOGS READ %s", buf);

    //////////////////
    fputs("data1\n", values->p_stdin);
    printf("LOGS 1\n");

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), values->p_stdout)==NULL);
    printf("LOGS READ %s", buf);

    //////////////////


    //////////////////
    fputs("data2\n", values->p_stdin);
    printf("LOGS 2\n");

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), values->p_stdout)==NULL);
    printf("LOGS READ %s", buf);

    //////////////////

    //////////////////
    fputs("data3\n", values->p_stdin);
    printf("LOGS 3\n");

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), values->p_stdout)==NULL);
    printf("LOGS READ %s", buf);

    //////////////////

    printf("LOGS 4\n");
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), values->p_stdout)==NULL);
    printf("LOGS READ %s", buf);
    // &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

    fclose(values->p_stdin);
    fclose(values->p_stdout);
    free(values);
    
    printf("HOST END\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**target.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    printf("TARGET BEGIN\n");
    
    char s[1000];
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("TARGET got 0: %s\n",s);

    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("TARGET got 1: %s\n",s);

    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("TARGET got 2: %s\n",s);
    
    
    printf("TARGET DONE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The current output is stuck at

```
HOST BEGIN
popen2() success
LOGS 0
```

Expected output:

```
HOST BEGIN
popen2() success
LOGS 0
LOGS READ TARGET BEGIN
LOGS 1
LOGS READ TARGET got 0: data1
LOGS 2
LOGS READ TARGET got 1: data2
LOGS 3
LOGS READ TARGET got 2: data3
LOGS 4
LOGS READ TARGET DONE
HOST END
```

The `target.c` executable is named `target.out`. Please do not change `target.c`. How can I write my `host.c` to converse with `target.c`?

**EDIT:**

I changed `target.c` to following and everything is working.
Thanks to @Ian Abbott to guiding me on the right path :)

**target.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    printf("TARGET BEGIN\n");

    
    char s[1000] = "dummy";
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("TARGET got 0: %s\n",s);

    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("TARGET got 1: %s\n",s);

    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("TARGET got 2: %s\n",s);
    
    
    printf("TARGET DONE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
HOST BEGIN
popen2() success
LOGS 0
LOGS READ TARGET BEGIN
LOGS 1
LOGS READ TARGET got 0: data1
LOGS 2
LOGS READ TARGET got 1: data2
LOGS 3
LOGS READ TARGET got 2: data3
LOGS 4
LOGS READ TARGET DONE
HOST END
```

It seems to me there is no way to accomplish this without changing `target.c`. This can be known from how in Google Kickstart interactive questions they ask us to make sure we flush the output.
There is nothing to take care of `target.c` flushing responsibilities from `host.c`.

Comment: If I remove all the `scanf` from the `target.c` it is working. It seems input to `target.c` executable is not working.

Comment: @zeitgeist What do you mean with "it is working" in your comment. Is this the solution of your problem? (--> write an answer) Is this additional information for the question? (--> [edit] your question) Describe the expected behavior in your question, add the expected output. What is the intention of the loops `while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), values->p_stdout)==NULL);`? This would mean "repeat as long as an error or end-of-file is present". I would expect that this condition will never change.

Comment: target.out will have set its `stdin` and `stdout` to fully buffered mode. Try calling `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("TARGET BEGIN\n");`.

Comment: Hi @Bodo by "it is working." I mean that I am able to print the `target.c` stdout as expected. However `target.c` is not able to read `stdin` at all as of now. The intention of `while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), values->p_stdout)==NULL);` is to try to read till we get any data.

Comment: @IanAbbott As I have mentioned "If I remove all the scanf from the `target.c` it is working." so the problem seems to lie in `target.c` stdin.

Comment: Problem _probably_ lies in host.c stdout, more precisely the buffering it does, never giving anything for target.c to reas.

Comment: @hyde I have used `setvbuf(values->p_stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` for `host.c` writing to stdin of `target.c` via pipe. Is it not enough?

Comment: Well removing all the `scanf` calls from target will automatically `flush` stdout when it exits.

Comment: @zeitgeist Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. The `fgets` loop will not "read till we get any data". It will be an endless loop in case of EOF or error, otherwise `fgets` will block until it can read a line of input and then exit from the loop. As others wrote, this is probably a buffering issue. A system call trace (`strace`)  might show what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely cause of the problem is that `target.out` is running with the `stdout` stream set to *fully buffered* `_IOFBF` mode. The C execution environment is allowed to initialize the `stdout` and `stdin` streams to fully buffered mode if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device (C17 7.21.3/7). The streams do in fact refer to pipe devices and GNU libc on Linux decides that pipes are not interactive devices, so freely sets the streams to *fully buffered* mode.

The first I/O sequence that `target.out` does is:

```
    printf("TARGET BEGIN\n");
    
    scanf("%s",s);
```

OP is hoping that the output from the `printf` call will have been automatically flushed to its output pipe before the `scanf` call reads from its input pipe. The GNU libc manual's section on [Flushing Buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html) has this as one of the circumstances when buffered output on a stream is automatically flushed:

> Whenever an input operation on *any* stream actually reads data from its file.

It is not clear to me what it means by "actually reads" because it would seem more useful if the flush occurred *before* it read an input stream. (EDIT: I think "actually reads" means it has used up all previously buffered input and now needs to read from the device.) It is also not what GNU libc actually does in practice.  The old GLIBC_2.0 interface has code to flush all the *line buffered* output streams before reading an input stream. The newer GLIBC interface is similar except it only flushes the `stdout` stream (and only if it is *line buffered*, as for the old GLIBC_2.0 interface).

From the above, it can be determined that GNU libc is *not* automatically flushing `stdout` to the output pipe before the `scanf` call reads from the input pipe. The output from the `printf` call will be stuck in the `stdout` stream's buffer.

This means that `host.out` and `target.out` are *both* reading from empty pipes at the same time, so no progress can be made.

There are two possible solutions that can be implemented in `target.c`:

1. The `stdout` stream can be set to something other than *fully buffered* mode. Setting it to *line buffered* mode will do. This should be done before the first call to `printf`:

   ```
       setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
   ```
2. Alternatively, the `stdout` stream could be explicitly flushed before each call to `scanf`:

   ```
       fflush(stdout);
       scanf("%s",s);
   ```

Either solution should result in the output from the `printf` call being flushed to the output pipe before the input pipe is read.

Comment: Thanks, man! I've accepted your answer and added an edit to the question.